# Clause type classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, nlp

We would like identify similar text (clauses) on a contract based on a trained corpus.

For instance:

**Contract - small sample**

```
NOW, THEREFORE, the parties hereto mutually agree as follows:

1. Scope of Services. The CONTRACTOR shall, in a proper and satisfactory manner as determined by OHA, provide all the goods and services set forth in Attachment – S1,
which is hereby made a part of this Contract.

2. Time of Performance. The performance required of the CONTRACTOR under this Contract shall be completed in accordance with the Time Schedule set forth in Attachment – S2, which is hereby made a part of this Contract.

3. Compensation. The CONTRACTOR shall be compensated according to the Compensation provision set forth in Attachment – S3, which is hereby made a part of this Contract.

4. Standards of Conduct Declaration. The Standards of Conduct Declaration of the CONTRACTOR is attached and is made a part of this Contract.
```

**Trained clauses**

We already have classified a few clauses from previous contracts. For instance:

```
#time_of_performance = 
[
    "Under this contract the performance required to be completed in accordance with the a predefined schedule."
,
    "The completion of each phase of the project will be used to define the performance of this contract"
,
    etc.
]
```

Where `#time_of_performance` is the classification for these clauses.

**Expected result**

Given the contract and the trained set, we would like to get parts/ranges of the texts and its classifications:

```
#time_of_performance = ["2. Time of Performance. The performance required of the CONTRACTOR under this Contract shall be completed in accordance with the Time Schedule set forth in Attachment – S2, which is hereby made a part of this Contract."]
```

Is there a known approach for this problem or a recommended processing pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Since all the sentences length are not highly varying, you can use sentence embeddings and do the clustering on top of that.

For example,

```
Text => USE => vector[1024] => KMeans
```

USE - [Universal sentence encoders](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4)

Kmeans - [SKlearn Module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

You can adjust the number of clusters using these [techniques.](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/determining-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-3-must-know-methods/#:%7E:text=The%20optimal%20number%20of%20clusters%20can%20be%20defined%20as%20follow,the%20number%20of%20clusters%20k.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are in terms of prior knowledge, but this [blog post](https://dida.do/blog/what-is-natural-language-processing-nlp) might get you started.

Comment: this a introduction to NLP. it's too broad